# col-md-6 não está funcionando em MVC

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

Criei um form usando `bootstrap.css` no site w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp com o seguinte codigo:

```
  <div class="container">
        <form role="form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 no-padding-left">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Código</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 no-padding-left">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>CNPJ</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 no-padding-left">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Nome Comercial</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 no-padding-left">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Razão Social</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 no-padding-left">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Endereço</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1 no-padding-left">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Numero</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </fieldset>
     </form>
 </div>
```

Lá funciona corretamente e o form fica como imaginei.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas dai eu copiei esse código exatamente como está(ainda não cheguei a parte de mesclar com os códigos `@Html` do RAZOR) e ele não renderiza legal, mas a linha RAZAO SOCIAL, que deveria ocupar toda a largura do FORM, não acontece independente se eu coloco 6, 7, 8... ou 12.

O form fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que esta impedindo que ela fique na largura correta?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O projeto ASP.NET MVC clássico configura algumas coisas indevidas, tipo esta.

Abra o arquivo `Content/Site.css` e comente ou retire o seguinte:

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Ou ainda, apague o arquivo. Apenas não esqueça de removê-lo do `BundleConfig.cs`.

Answer (score 0):

Simples, o grid do boostrap possui classes para desktops e mixed displays porém o recurso utilizado para identificar a midia é o width, sua exibição está fora dos tamanhos padrões de um desktop dessa forma os seletores do grid não funcionam.

Consultando a documentação do boostrap em: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ você poderá ler mais sobre este tipo de problema mas para resolver este bug basta substituir o `col-md-#numero#` pelo `col-xs-#numero#` vide meu exemplo:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-1 no-padding-left">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Razão Social</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 no-padding-left">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Endereço</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 no-padding-left">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Numero</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Felipe alterei todos os md para xs, mas não funcionou. Apresentou o mesmo problema, com a diferença de que o form agora não ficou renderezida no meio da tela e sim a esquerda.

Comment: Estranho cara usando exatamente o seu html vide exemplo acima funcionou perfeitamente, teste removendo todos os arquivos.css e deixando apenas o bootstrap