# Bootstrap - Como aumentar o tamanho da coluna do input?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-3

Segue o código:

Na página index:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="minhaModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="conteudoModal"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Na _PartialView:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Criar</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-12" placeholder="Username">
          <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default">?</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Criar" />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
</div>
```

Consigo alterar o tamanho de: col-xs-1 até 4. Não consigo alterar para col-xs-12.

Segue a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem acima, onde tem a linha vermelha, o input deveria compreender toda a linha vermelha.

Segui o exemplo desse site: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_sizing.asp

Já tentei alterar o tamanho da coluna pelo `width` e nada funciona.

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [col-md-6 não está funcionando em MVC](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117287/col-md-6-n%c3%a3o-est%c3%a1-funcionando-em-mvc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você iniciou o projeto em Asp.Net MVC5, o visual studio cria um arquivo chamado **Site.css**. Ele fica em `~/Content/Site.css`

Neste arquivo, possui a seguinte linha:

```
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Este **css** está dizendo que os elementos `input`, `select` e `textarea` terão o tamanho máximo de 200px.

Altere este tamanho, comente/remova esta parte ou altere o **css** manualmente. Qualquer uma dessas opções irá resolver o seu problema.